# How to use UIImage+SDAdditions

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to use the above category for `UIImage` - [Found Here](http://blog.logichigh.com/2008/06/05/uiimage-fix/)

The reason for use is that I am having the user take a photo using the Camera/Picker. I then need to display the image selected in a `UIImageView`.

I would like to keep the orientation information of the image but scale it down slightly, for performance and best fit to the image view.

How do I implement to use this category? I am unsure how to make the call to the cat, do I call the method in some way?

At present, I have some delegate methods for the picker:

```
#pragma mark - UIImagePickerDelegate Methods
//delegate methode will be called after picking photo either from camera or library
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    self.collectedImage = image;
    NSLog(@"the collect image orientation is: %i",image.imageOrientation);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.collectedImage = image;
NSLog(@"--------------------collected image information----------------------");
NSLog(@"the collected image orientation is: %i",image.imageOrientation);
NSLog(@"the image width is: %f",self.collectedImage.size.width);
NSLog(@"the image height is: %f",self.collectedImage.size.height);

// scale the image
UIImage *newCollectedImage = [self.collectedImage scaleWithMaxDimension:([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
self.collectedImage = newCollectedImage;
NSLog(@"--------------------collected NEW image information----------------------");
NSLog(@"the new collected image orientation is: %i",self.collectedImage.imageOrientation);
NSLog(@"the new image width is: %f",self.collectedImage.size.width);
NSLog(@"the new image height is: %f",self.collectedImage.size.height);
```